# how to convert matlab videofilereader output for blobanalysis input

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

I want search a single video frame for any visual blobs.
but blobAnalyzer() does not accept the frame from VideoFileReader().

Seems like a problem converting from video frame to binary image?

THE ERROR IS:
Error using vision.BlobAnalysis/step
Data with more than two dimensions is not supported
for this System object.

Error in test (line 20)
        [areas, centroids, bboxes] =
        obj.blobAnalyser.step( video_frame );

% Get video frame:
    videoFileLeft = 'handshake_left.avi';

```
readerLeft = vision.VideoFileReader(videoFileLeft, 'VideoOutputDataType', 'uint8');

video_frame = readerLeft.step();
```

% Parse blobs:
    obj.blobAnalyser = vision.BlobAnalysis('BoundingBoxOutputPort', true, ...
    'AreaOutputPort', true, 'CentroidOutputPort', true, ...
    'MinimumBlobArea', 400);

```
    [areas, centroids, bboxes] = obj.blobAnalyser.step( video_frame );
```

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: Error using vision.BlobAnalysis/step
Data with more than two dimensions is not supported
for this System object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading a rgb video but the blobAnalyser supports only binary images (black and white). Use `im2bw` to convert.